# Order by after element

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do a query that orders by a field after a certain element id. I am trying to implement pagination based on the last returned element, and want to be able to both order elements a property and return the next paged based on the last element of the previous page.
For example a user may ask for 25 elements after element with id = 10 sorted on cost.

Imagine you have:

> id  | name    | price
>
> 1   | Fish    | 5
>
> 2   | Burger  | 2
>
> 3   | Veggies | 6

If we want to get after id=2 sorted by price it should return

> 2 | Burger  | 2
>
> 1 | Fish    | 5
>
> 3 | Veggies | 6

If we want to get after id=1 sorted by price it should return

> 1 | Fish    | 5
>
> 3 | Veggies | 6

Comment: Show us what you have got so far.

Comment: SELECT top 25 elements FROM TABLE1 WHERE id>10 ORDER BY cost ASC?

Comment: I don't have a good idea how to start it. Added a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Well, it is not clear in your examples either. In the 3 cases where I see `id = X` in the question I don't see the match in the output example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE id >= 10
ORDER BY cost ASC
LIMIT 25;
```

EDIT:

According to your new information, you can do that with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE price >= (SELECT price from Table1 WHERE id = 2)
ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 25;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/626d5/4)</kbd>**